# how to get data from contract A, and use it in contract B

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether

I have gotten the data correctly from contract A...I cannot figure out how to use it in Contrtact B. One search led me to believe it may not be possible.. However what would be the point of Contract B even getting the data from A then? So I conclude there must be a way..

I have used..

```
function getbasePercent() external view returns(uint256) {
TokenContract a = TokenContract(tokenaddress);
 return  a.basePercent() ;
}
```

how can i have Contract B use the value of b.basePercent ??

Comment: Can you post code of basePercent in contract A?

Comment: You are doing it correctly, as far as what you've posted